# Jquery Ajax call to C# Web Service Error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, iis-7

I am trying to make an AJAX call using jQuery to a C# Web Service located under the same website. No matter what I find/try, I keep on receiving a 500 error as such:

```
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/MyTest'.
```

**jQuery AJAX call from web page**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://172.1.1.10/MYService/MyService.asmx/MyTest',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fail");
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**Web Service (MyService.asmx) Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string MyTest()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

and yes I have the following uncommented at the top:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

When I try to load my web page, I get the alert window saying "Fail". This is when I receive the 500 error (see top of post).

Too many people suggested adding this to the web service's web.config:

**Web Service (Web.config)**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Upon adding this, I can hit the local machine with this address:

```
http://172.1.1.10/MYService/MyService.asmx/MyTest
```

and I get the proper response of "Hello World". Prior to adding this I would get the same 500 Error message locally.

Both the web service and web site are setup on the same IIS instance, each as its own application, under the same web site in IIS. I know it is not a cross-domain issue because I am not getting the 503 error that you'd typically receive if this were true, nor am I getting the 404 error of File Not Found.

I've scoured the web and cannot seem to find a resolution to this.

Comment: Canyou try to using genegic handlers i your project?

Comment: Is your web app on the same port 80, and also with http protocol?

Comment: Is your web app on the same domain as the service?

Comment: Yes they are both on the same domain. Both Applications (Web Service and Web Page) are nested underneath the Default Web Site in IIS. They run on Port 80. I can use the same domain name to hit both pages technically.

Comment: I created a new project from scratch and put your code their, and it's working perfectly fine. Either you have cross-domain issues somehow or you have some extra handlers in your web service project which affect on parsing the request.

Comment: If you go to your server, does it work if you browse to /MYService/MyService.asmx and invoke the `MyTest` method?

Comment: @MaxShmelev When you tested this code, was the Web Service in a separate project from the web page you were using?

Comment: In Chrome, start the developer tools and then make your Ajax call (or use Firebug in Firefox and enable the console). Are there any errors in the console? In my case the call was blocked due to the same origin policy.

Comment: @nick_w This helped me come to the problem, thanks! Never utilized the Console feature of Chrome before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nick_w, using Chrome's Console feature provided me with the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.1.1.10/MYService/MyService.asmx/MyTest. Origin http://mydomain.mysitename.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I discovered that when I was browsing to my site, I was using the domain name:

```
http://mydomain.mysitename.com
```

Whereas when I was calling the web service in code, I was using the IP Address:

```
http://172.1.1.10
```

Thus I technically was experiencing the cross-domain issue. Once I hit my site at the IP Address, or changed the webservice call to:

```
http://mydomain.mysitename.com/MyService/MyService.asmx/MyTest
```

Then it resolved just fine. I did need to update my code as such:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://mydaomin.mysitename.com/MYService/MyService.asmx/MyTest',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (data, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fail");
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Note, I added ".d" to the alert as it was returning an "Object object" rather then the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since it says that the request format is unrecognized you do not need to send data in the ajax call.Try removing the data field data:"{}" from the ajax call and see if that works.Just use:

```
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://172.1.1.10/MYService/MyService.asmx/MyTest',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fail");
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work, same error, same issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you able to see the json response in the browser when you hit the endpoint?

Comment: I get the "Fail" message and the errorThrown is "undefined". If I check Fiddler when browsing I get the same 500 Error. I guess I'm not fully understanding your question.

Comment: Do you see your messages as POST method in Fiddler?

Comment: Looking at the Raw data in the 500 Error in Fiddler, I see the following "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" for the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can add global class in your services and add following code in `Application_BeginRequest` function:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```